# Pygame line appearing broken

Tags: python, vector, pygame

So I was making a turtle like object in python and I had a issue which got resolved.

Now I am noticing a intersting or rather annoying thing that when I attempt to a make a square with lt(90) or rt(270), one of the line appears broken.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.math import Vector2
from math import sin, cos, radians

class Turtle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vector = Vector2(0, 0)
        self.angle = 0
        self.pen_width = 25
        self.pen_color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.pen_visible = True

    def forward(self, win, distance):
        start = self.vector
        offset = Vector2(sin(radians(self.angle)), cos(radians(self.angle)))
        offset *= distance
        end = start + offset
        if self.is_down():
            pygame.draw.line(win, self.pen_color, start, end, self.pen_width)
        self.vector = end
    fd = forward

    def backward(self, win, distance):
        self.forward(win, -distance)
    bk = back = backward

    def left(self, angle):
        self.angle = (self.angle + angle) % 360
        self.angle
    lt = left

    def right(self, angle):
        self.left(-angle)
    rt = right

    def goto(self, win, pos):
        if self.is_down():
            pygame.draw.line(win, self.pen_color, self.vector, pos, self.pen_width)
            self.vector = Vector2(pos)
    setposition = setpos = goto

    def set_angle(self, angle= None):
        if not angle:
            return self.angle
        self.angle = angle

    def position(self):
        return self.vector.xy
    pos = position

    def sety(self, y):
        self.vector.y = y

    def setx(self, x):
        self.vector.x = x

    def xcor(self):
        return self.vector.x

    def ycor(self):
        return self.vector.y

    def penup(self):
        self.pen_visible = False
    pu = up = penup

    def pendown(self):
        self.pen_visible = True
    pd = down = pendown

    def is_down(self):
        return self.pen_visible

    def write(self, win, font_label):
        win.blit(font_label, self.vector)

def test():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.font.init()

    WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500
    CAPTION = 'Caption'
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption(CAPTION)

    FPS = 60
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    mytut = Turtle()
    mytut.pen_width = 5
    mytut.goto(win, (250, 250))
    mytut.pen_color = '#00FF00'
    for _ in range(4):
        mytut.fd(win, 100)
        mytut.rt(270)

    while True:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Screenshot -  [image: Broken Line]

Moreover this issue does not occur when I use lt(270) or rt(90).

I dont know why this happens in pygame. I feel it may related to some floating point numbers being a bit off but dont know exactly why?

I need help to fix this!

Comment: No the line is broken in between, I will also add a screenshot.

Comment: The line is "broken in between", because the start and end point are not at the same height.

Comment: @Rabbid76 How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by a floating point inaccuracy. [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinates to solve the issue. You can further improve the representation, by drawing a small circle at the end of the line:

```py
class Turtle:
    # [...]

    def forward(self, win, distance):
        start = self.vector
        offset = Vector2(sin(radians(self.angle)), cos(radians(self.angle)))
        offset *= distance
        end = start + offset
        if self.is_down():
            s = round(start.x), round(start.y)
            e = round(end.x), round(end.y)
            pygame.draw.line(win, self.pen_color, s, e, self.pen_width)
            pygame.draw.circle(win, self.pen_color, e, self.pen_width // 2)
        self.vector = end
```

[image]